# How to use the block "select menu with external options" while using the socket mode in slack bot?

Tags: slack, bolt, slack-block-kit

So I have created a slack-bot using the bolt-python framework and I have enabled socket mode for better security as it won't expose public endpoints.

This bot is intended for my company to integrate it's APIs with slack. The internal API should send list of options to a dynamic select menu in slack. However I can't find a way to achieve that using socket mode.

Generally(w/o socket mode), I can specify the URL for external options to load.
[As displayed here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCRSB.png)

There is no proper documentation available. Does anyone know a workaround for this?, I am a novice when it comes to handling APIs and also to slack.

Thanks.